# Handlebars.js and google spreadsheet show/hide content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I am trying to get my content brought into handlebars from my google spreadsheets to be in  tags that I can show/hide.  When you click on the link it shows one panel of content and hides another panel of content.  I have the handlebars bringing the content in from the two google spreadsheets but when I add try to do the hide/show panels it does not work. I had the hide/show panels showing up at one time but with no content from the handlebars in it.

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justawebbie/AcW97/17/

Here is the javascript section:

```
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
            else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }


// Define spreadsheet URL.
   var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjlSK7_zXoNHdEoyWDYxb3hnZi1xWkl1TVQ0eERBQ2c#gid=0';
   var mySpreadsheet2='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjlSK7_zXoNHdEpYUEg0VTJ0Rlpzb2RUOVZfLU5oX0E#gid=0'

// Compile the Handlebars template for HR leaders.
   var HRTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#hr-template').html());
   var HRTemplate3 = Handlebars.compile($('#hr-template3').html());
// Load top five HR leaders.
    $('#hr').sheetrock({
       url: mySpreadsheet,
       sql: "select A,B,C,N,M,O where B contains 'yes' order by A desc",
       headersOff: true,
       headers: 2,
       rowHandler: HRTemplate
    });
    $('#hr3').sheetrock({
       url: mySpreadsheet2,
       sql: "select A,C,D,E order by A desc",
       headersOff: true,
       headers: 2,
       rowHandler: HRTemplate3
    });
```

Here the HTML section:

```
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('sec1');">Certificates</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('sec2');">Minors</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="sec1" style="background-color:pink;">
         <div id="hr" class="table">
            <script id="hr-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
             <div id='table-row'>
                       <div id='first-cell'><a href='{{cells.N}}' class='left-link'>{{cells.A}}</a></div>
               <div id='second-cell'><a href='{{cells.O}}' class='right-link'>{{cells.M}}</a></div>
                </script>
           </div>
     </div>  
     <div id="sec2" style="background-color:#eee;"> 
          <div id="hr3" class="table">
           <script id="hr-template3" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div id='table-row'>
                        <div id='first-cell'><a href='{{cells.D}}' class='left-link'>{{cells.A}}</a></div>
                <div id='second-cell'><a href='{{cells.E}}' class='right-link'>{{cells.C}}</a></div>
                     </div>
               </script>
           </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler appears to be having issues loading the libraries, but it works fine when I build out the page locally. Try this zip file and see if you still have any questions.

http://cris.lc/qtpzm

Comment: Thank you for the help.  It seems they div's hang up on the toggle and one does not hide as the other shows up. If I do position:absolute then the div's do not expand with the handlebars input.

Comment: Your javascript function is set to only change one of them at a time.

You'll need to modify your visibility function to hide the active element, or you could write a helper function like this:

http://pastebin.com/ETYw3hMN.

You would then need to have your anchors call the new function:

`<li><a href="#" onclick="tradeVisibility('sec1','sec2');">Certificates</a>`

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back on this Cristos.  I tried it and I am feeling dumber and dumber on this but will get back on it this weekend will keep you posted.